# Android X86 Stuck on detecting android x86 on VMWARE with AMD CPU

Tags: x86-processors

If there's a link to a fix in another thread please tell me, but for now here's my problem

I want to use Instagram on an android emulator to upload reels since my phone is dead and I'm under lockdown, Neither any of the Advertised emulators work, I tried Nox,Memu,Bluestacks and LDPlayer and all of them when I install instagram the app stop working.

So back to the point;
I installed VMWare and download an android X86 VMDK and iso image, both doesn't boot, The iso one restarts on detecting android x86 and vmdk one gets stuck on detecting android x86, I tried Virtual box, same result.

How do I fix it?

Specs: Amd Athlon II x45,4GB Ram,Nvidia GT 220

Comment: So the Instagram web site isn't sufficient for you? Regarding Andorid-x86 we had a number of questions about that emulator and they all mention that the x86/32bit variant does not boot/work. Only the 64bit version seems to work.

Comment: I want to upload reels and photos, which is something you can't do anymore on instagram website

Comment: Which Instagram app version do you try to install? Make sure you are using the x86 version https://apkpure.com/de/instagram/com.instagram.android/variant/179.0.0.31.132-APK besides that I would recommend Genymotion or the standard emulator from Android SDK.

Comment: Genymotion gives an error when booting, I tried it

Comment: Then your CPU most likely misses the required virtualization features or those features are disabled in BIOS. In any way your PC lacks the minimum requirements regarding RAM. An recent Android emulator typically requires 2-4GB RAM for itself.